# how to read lines of ECDSA recover public key from signature in assembly?

Tags: assembly, ethereum, solidity, opcode

im looking into how to read the ECDSA recovery output in assembly in etherscan

```
function tryRecover(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) internal pure returns (address, RecoverError) {
        // Check the signature length
        // - case 65: r,s,v signature (standard)
        // - case 64: r,vs signature (cf https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2098) _Available since v4.1._
        if (signature.length == 65) {
            bytes32 r;
            bytes32 s;
            uint8 v;
            // ecrecover takes the signature parameters, and the only way to get them
            // currently is to use assembly.
            /// @solidity memory-safe-assembly
            assembly {
                r := mload(add(signature, 0x20))
                s := mload(add(signature, 0x40))
                v := byte(0, mload(add(signature, 0x60)))
            }
            return tryRecover(hash, v, r, s);
        } else if (signature.length == 64) {
            bytes32 r;
            bytes32 vs;
            // ecrecover takes the signature parameters, and the only way to get them
            // currently is to use assembly.
            /// @solidity memory-safe-assembly
            assembly {
                r := mload(add(signature, 0x20))
                vs := mload(add(signature, 0x40))
            }
            return tryRecover(hash, r, vs);
        } else {
            return (address(0), RecoverError.InvalidSignatureLength);
        }
    }
```

in there any way i could read the opcode to get the output of this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can get it from etherscan since it's an internal function. It should be possible by looking at the trace opcode by opcode but it's difficult. I suggest this tool https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/tree/master/src/hevm

Answer (score 0):

This library helps you to recover public key from ECDSA signed message
https://github.com/0xcyphered/secp256k1-solidity

Example:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@0xcyphered/secp256k1-solidity/contracts/SECP256K1.sol";
contract Example {
    function recoverPersonalSignPublicKey(
        bytes32 message,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        string memory header = '\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32';
        bytes32 _message = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(header, message));
        (uint256 x, uint256 y) = SECP256K1.recover(uint256(_message), v - 27, uint256(r), uint256(s));
        return abi.encodePacked(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32988508)